# Biblatex conditional punctuation depending on field value

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I am using the style `authoryear` in Biblatex and I currently have a comma after the journal name as follows

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1, }
```

The output I obtain is for example, `Journal of Medcine, 8: 45-60` where the journal name is followed by a comma, volume, and page numbers. In some cases the journal field has the value `In press.` .

So based on the above format, i obtain the following output `In press.,`

My question is, how can I add a condition such that, when the `journaltitle` equals `In press.` the comma is excluded?

EDIT:

See below example.

[image]

Comment: You should not add the comma to `\DeclareFieldFormat`. Suppose, for some reason  there's nothing after the journal title. It is `biblatex`'s job to take care of the punctuation. If you want conditional punctuation, you will probably have to patch  the article bibdriver.

Comment: `biblatex` provides the field `substate` to record this type of information. The information that an article is "In press", should be recorded in the field for the journal title.

Comment: @Bernard If I don't put the comma in ``\DeclareFieldFormat`` there will be no punctuation, just a space.

Comment: @Guido I am not sure I follow. I have already recorded "In press." in the journal title field. I have included the point there and thought that I could write a condition so that the comma would be removed if the field value is "In press."

Comment: The `biblatex` way would be  `journaltitle = {Journal of Medcine}, pubstate = {In press}`, not `journaltitle = {Journal of Medicine, in press}`.

Comment: @Guido: the field is `pubstate`.

Comment: @roland: you just have to patch the `article` driver. That's easy with the `xpatch` package.

Comment: auto**r**correcrion? (Note in my preceding post, I mentioned a `dirver` :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` provides the `pubstate` field to record information about "In press" and similar. Accordingly, the `journaltitle` should not be used to store such information.

In case one has such information in `journaltitle`, it is possible to use `biber` ability to manipulate bibtex entries dynamically to put the information in the appropriate field.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, 
                        match=\regexp{,\s+in\s+press},
                        fieldset=pubstate,
                        fieldvalue={in press}]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, 
                        match=\regexp{,\s+in\s+press},
                        replace={}]
    }
  }
}
```

The above operation, checks if the `journaltitle` contains the string `, in press` and copy it to the `pubstate` field. Then, in the second step it remove the string from `journaltitle`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. In some cases, when the paper hasn't been published (Working paper), the ``journaltitle`` field contains the words ``In press.`` instead of the name of the journal.

Comment: I added a picture in the question. I'm referring to the first reference which ends with "In press.,"

Comment: Do not use the `journaltitle` information. Use `pubstate` field.